# The screen only shows one component, when I use my custom components in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

My screen only shows one component.

Hi, i'm new in react native and i created a component. When i use my component, only shows in my screen the first one and ignores de rest of de code. This is my screen, only shows the first one (don't pay attention to the source atribute).

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { BigImgButton } from "../components/Buttons";

const Home = () => {
    return(
        <View>
            
            <BigImgButton
                onPress = {() => {alert('text')}}
                source = {require('source')}
            />

        <Text>TEST</Text>

            <BigImgButton
                onPress = {() => {alert('test')}}
                source = {require('source')}
            />
            

            
        </View>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Here i share the component.

```
import react from "react";
import { Touchable } from "react-native";
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export function SmallImgButton(props) {

    const { onPress, source } = props

    return ( 
        <TouchableOpacity
            style = {{
                ...styles.smallButton,
            }}
            onPress={ onPress }
        >
            <Image 
            source={ source }
            style = {{
                ...styles.smallButtonImage
            }}
            />

        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

export function BigImgButton(props) {

    const { onPress, source } = props

    return ( 
        <TouchableOpacity
            style = {{
                ...styles.bigButton,
            }}
            onPress={ onPress }
        >
            <Image 
            source={ source }
            style = {{
                ...styles.bigButtonImage
            }}
            />

        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    smallButton: {
        width: '19%',
        height: '44.4%',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginVertical: 15
    },

    smallButtonImage: {
        width: 75,
        height: 80,
    },

    bigButton: {
        width: '42%',
        height: '80%',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginVertical: 15,
    },

    bigButtonImage: {
        width: 170,
        height: 165,
    }
})
```